# c# string query put null for sql server parameter

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008

I know this question was asked many times, but i am not able to find a solution for it

This is my code

```
  string query = @"SELECT *
    FROM SMSMessage
    WHERE (respondCode  IS @respondCode)
and (sentOn > '08/26/2016')
       ";
                //string query = "select * from SMSMessage";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Utilities.getConnectionString());
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@respondCode", DBNull.Value);
```

I want the responseCode to be null,

I am getting error:

> syntax error near @responseCode

when I do this `responseCode is NULL`, there is no syntax error, but the query for some reaonse doesn't bring any result

Help please

Comment: If the NULL is fixed then you don't need a parameter. Do you want to find all records from SMSMessage where RespondCode IS null and sent after that date?

Comment: @Steve yes exactly

Comment: Then why not _WHERE (respondCode  IS NULL) AND ...._ Pay attention to the string format for your Date constant also because the correct interpretation of that constant depends on the sql server localization

Comment: @Steve that is the thing, you got me, please look at my comment to the answer below, the code is no working, it gives the same results always. do you mean the and should be capital letter?

Comment: @Steve the format of the SentOn is date time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use directly IS NULL and not passing any parameter, but the most important change is how do you apply the date constant in your query statement.
Assuming you use the Italian locale in your sql server database I would use

```
string query = @"SELECT * SMSMessage
                 WHERE respondCode  IS NULL
                 AND (sentOn > CONVERT(DateTime, '26/08/2016', 105))
```

[T-SQL Convert docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

On the contrary I would look carefully to the value passed for the sentOn condition. If this value changes dynamically it is better to use a parameter for this value. In this way the query optimizer of sql server will be able to build a better (faster) execution plan

```
string query = @"SELECT * SMSMessage
                 WHERE respondCode  IS NULL
                 AND sentOn > @dateLimit";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Utilities.getConnectionString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateLimit", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(2016, 8, 26);
```

Comment: what does 105 mean please ?

Comment: i understood from the first answer that i can't pass "null" as it is in this case because i have two conditions, are you sure that it is correct the way you passed null please ?

Comment: I am not passing NULL, there is no parameter in the query above.

Comment: yes there is respondCode parameter in my code, that i want to pass null for it, in your query you passed null as string, and in the first query the guy said that if i have two conditions, i can't pass null as string. you got me please ?

Comment: The point is: if you search always for records that have NULL in the respondCode then there is no need of a parameter there. Just write the IS NULL in the query and that's all.

Comment: i think this convert solved the problem, i need to wait to deploy again and come back to you,thank you +one

Comment: However, consider to use a parameter for the sentOn condition. Probably this date limit will change dynamically and passing a parameter of type DateTime will help the optimizer in building a faster execution plan for your query.

Comment: actually the date condition is just temporary, i won't use it when i finish cleaning the data. last thing please, can i extend your solution to ` AND (sentOn between CONVERT(DateTime, '26/08/2016', 105) and CONVERT(DateTime, '26/09/2016')` ?

Comment: Yes but do not use Between, use >= and <=

Comment: Remember that a DateTime has a time component <= 29/06/2016 00:00 doesn't include record with 29/06/2016 00:01

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want this

```sql
Where (respondCode = @respondCode or @respondCode is null)
  and sentOn > '08/26/2016'
```

When a value is passed to `@respondCode` parameter the records will be filter based on `@respondCode` and `sentOn > '08/26/2016'`.

When nothing is passed to `@respondCode` parameter (ie) `NULL`, then records will be filtered only based on `sentOn > '08/26/2016'`

As mentioned in comments by Steve, If you need records only when `respondCode` is `NULL` then no need of that variable just hardcode the `NULL` condition in `Where` clause

```sql
Where respondCode is null
  and sentOn > '08/26/2016'
```

Comment: It is not working, and it is not throwing an error, it allows gives the same results, even though the results are not correct

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Can you add some sample data and expected result

Comment: when i check the count of the returning rows from that query it is always the same, though i am changing the responseCode to a value not null

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - can you post the query you are using

Comment: i posted it it is in the question

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - common the query present will not even compile post the working query you are using

Comment: `SELECT id
    FROM SMSMessage
    WHERE (respondCode  IS NULL)
AND (SentOn > '08/26/2016') ` this is the query working on sql server, that is what i would like to use from c#

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - What do you meant by saying working. Is it working as per the expectation in `SQL SERVER`. If yes then you are doing something wrong in C# code